# MySQL IN array only processes its first value

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am programmatically creating a PDO statement using PHP.

The PDO prepared statement is:

`` UPDATE `log` SET `id` = ? WHERE `id` IN ( ? ); ``

Where the variable content in the `IN` array are integers.

The first `?` is a single integer. The second `?` are integers in an array, so I am imploding them to the string `1,2,3` that would normally fit in the `IN` array.

So the full deal is:

```
public function mergeIDs($newID,$changeTheseIDs){ // (integer and array of integers, respectively)
    $inSet = implode(',',$changeTheseIDs);
    $query = $this->connect()->prepare("UPDATE `log` SET `id` = ? WHERE `id` IN ( ? );");
    $query->execute([$newID,$changeTheseIDs]);
}
```

**The issue seems to be that the SQL only processes the FIRST of the integer IDs that are inserted in the `IN` array.** Any ID matching one of the integers in the `IN` array should be changed.

If I run the SQL in the SQL tool on my server like this:

`` UPDATE `log` SET `id` = 5 WHERE `id` IN ( 1,2,3 ); ``

It works, and I get all IDs that were 1, 2, or 3 changed to 5.

But my PDO version changes only the 1s to 5s. 2s and 3s are left the same.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a `?` for each integer in the IN clause, you can't just have one.

```
public function mergeIDs($newID,$changeTheseIDs){ // (integer and array of integers, respectively)
    $inPH = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($changeTheseIDs), '?'));
    $query = $this->connect()->prepare("UPDATE `log` SET `id` = ? WHERE `id` IN ( {$inPH} );");
    $query->execute([$newID, ...$changeTheseIDs]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you both. These are great answers, but I expect the question will be cashiered. I searched like a dog for the question that is referenced above, but SO's algorithm showed me nothing of the sort when I submitted the question. All in a day's work.

Comment: @Parapluie don't use SO search. Use google with `site stackoverflow.com`. If you just add the word PDO to your title the dupe comes up on the first page.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this :

```
public function mergeIDs($newID,$changeTheseIDs){ // (integer and array of integers, respectively)
$mergeSet = array_merge([$newID],$changeTheseIDs);
$marks = array_fill(0, count($changeTheseIDs), '?');
$query = $this->connect()->prepare("UPDATE `log` SET `id` = ? WHERE `id` IN (". implode(',',  $marks) .");");
$query->execute($mergeSet);
}
```